# Prase.com REST API related array of objects issue

Tags: arrays, api, rest, associations, parse-platform

I have two arrays in my _User table: hasCreated and isMemberOf that hold group objects belonging to a Group table, and I have the following Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Group', function(request, response) {

    var creator = request.user;
    if (!_.isObject(creator)) {
        response.error('creator is not specified');
    }
    else {
        var group = request.object;
        var isCreate = group.isNew();

        //        Group is being created
        if (isCreate) {
            if (!_.isString(group.get('title'))) {
                response.error('group title is required');
            }
            else {
                group.set('createdById', creator.id);
                response.success();
            }
        }
        //        Group is being updated
        else {
            response.success();
        }
    }
});

Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Group', function(request) {

    var creator = request.user;
    var group = request.object;
    var wasGroupCreated = !group.existed();

    if (wasGroupCreated) {

        creator.addUnique('hasCreated', group);
        creator.addUnique('isMemberOf', group);

        creator.save();
    }
});

Parse.Cloud.afterDelete('Group', function(request) {

    var creator = request.user;
    var group = request.object;

    creator.remove('hasCreated', group);
    creator.remove('isMemberOf', group);

    creator.save();
});
```

When I POST to a Group, it happens as expected, but when I GET User with

```
includeKey=isMemberOf&hasCreated
```

I get the following:

```
hasCreated: [
    {
        __type: Object,
        className: Group,
        createdAt: 2014 - 06 - 04T18: 59: 02.325Z,
        createdById: abc,
        …
    }
    {
        __type: Pointer,
        className: Group,
        objectId: def
    }
    {
        __type: Pointer,
        className: Group,
        objectId: ghi
    }]
isMemberOf: [
    {
        __type: Object,
        className: Group,
        createdAt: 2014 - 06 - 04T18: 59: 02.325Z,
        createdById: abc,
        …
    }
    {
        __type: Pointer,
        className: Group,
        objectId: def
    }
    {
        __type: Pointer,
        className: Group,
        objectId: ghi
    }]
```

So basically, I only get back one of the three groups in its entirety, and the _type fields are different as well. Here is what I have in the User table in both hasCreated and isMemberOf array fields:

```
[{
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Group",
    "objectId": "abc"
}, {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Group",
    "objectId": "def"
}, {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Group",
    "objectId": "ghi"
}]
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to get the full objects for each of the groups. Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: Does anybody have any idea? Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one looks like it was a temporary issue (that lasted days for me) with Parse. include (not includeKey) has been reliably giving me full objects for quite a while now.